# CSS inherited style not overwriting

Tags: html, css

Style and HTML code:

```css
#fullmenu li{
        background:red;
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    }
    li.tab a{
        border-left: 1px solid #000;
    }
    li.tab:hover ul.content{
        display:block;
    }
    ul.content{
        background:blue;
        border-style:none;
        display:none;
    }
    ul.content li{
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
```

```html
    <ul id="fullmenu">
    <li class="tab"><a href=#>A</a>
        <ul class="content">
            <li><a href=#>A.1</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>A.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

The problem I'm having is twofold, but appears to be affected by the same thing.
I'm trying to overwrite the background color (in un-abridged background is gradient. So no, I can't just change it to 'blue') for the ul, "class".
Next, its a bit hard to see, but the left and bottom border will not overwrite and doubles up for the 'content li'.
Both seem to be inheritance problems, and I cannot figure it out. I've been scouring and fiddling for hours now, and can't seem to get it to work.
Please help.

Comment: you should check out an article such as [CSS Specificity: Things you should know](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to go over how rules are applied based on your definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Since id selectors take precedence over class selectors so this would fix the nested list:

```
ul#fullmenu ul.content{
    background:blue;
    border-style:none;
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```css
#fullmenu li{
    background:red;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
li.tab a{
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
ul.content{
    border-style:none;
    display:none;
}
#fullmenu ul.content li{
    background:blue;
}
ul.content li{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
li.tab:hover ul.content{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="fullmenu">
<li class="tab">
    <a href=#>A</a>
    <ul class="content">
        <li><a href=#>A.1</a></li>
        <li><a href=#>A.2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

or this

```css
#fullmenu >li{
    background:red;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
li.tab a{
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
li.tab:hover ul.content{
    display:block;
}
ul.content{
    background:blue;
    border-style:none;
    display:none;
}
ul.content li{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul id="fullmenu">
<li class="tab">
    <a href=#>A</a>
    <ul class="content">
        <li><a href=#>A.1</a></li>
        <li><a href=#>A.2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```